# In Typeahead, unable to subscribe to service to get data to bind to typeahead search

Tags: angular, angular6, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

i'm using ngbootstrap typeahead (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#http)

as per example mentioned we need to return observable to `[ngbTypeahead]="search"`

we're expecting below result from API

`{
    "data": {
        "groupNames": [
            "group level one",
            "group level two",
            "group level one",
            "group level two"
        ]
    }
}`

from this return result we need to filter by containing word.

`search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map((term) => term.length < 1 ? [] :
        this.productService.getGroups().subscribe((response) => {
          if (response && response.data) {
            return response.data.groupNames.filter((response) => response.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1);
          }
        },
        ),
      ),
    )`

Question :

how do i return below result as observable to typahead property

`return response.data.groupNames.filter((response) => response.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1);`

( note - we're fetching whole data from service and from result we're doing filter result as per user type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

returning from a subscription callback makes almost no sense. You could try to replace subscribe with switchMap and return events from a stream, rather than trying to return events in subscription. I guess working example would look like:

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((term) => term.length < 1 ? of([]) :
        this.productService.getGroups().pipe(
          filter((response) => response && response.data)
          map((response) => response.data.groupNames.filter((response) => response.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1))
        )
      ),
    )
```